# Need information on Session Less cookie

Tags: asp.net

I am aware of cookie less session. Can you please tell me about **session less cookie**?
if any relative links please share.

Comment: [Cookieless ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) Straight from MSDN...really, is Google that hard to use?

Comment: Google is not that hard to use...But My concern was about SessionLess Cookie which I just made Bold in my question. Is my question is that difficult to understand?

Comment: You asked about sessionless cookies and for any related links.  You have two answers below and I gave you the link straight from MSDN.  What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Dai's answer is what I was looking for. I will accept that answer once I will be sure about that answer. You are telling about cookieless session again and again which I clearly mentioned in my question that I am aware if cookieless session

Comment: Ah...got it now.  I thought they were the same thing - my mistake and my apologies.

Comment: No issues, If you get something on it please share. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "Session-less cookie". This is not a technical term used in web development, nor is it in any HTTP specification.

Cookies can be used to store Session IDs on the client, but only one cookie is needed to do this, all other cookies are non-session cookies in this respect.

Another interpretation concerns cookie lifetime: Cookies stored on the client can either expire when the browser window closes, or with an absolute expiration. The former kind are often referred to as "[browser] session cookies" because they last the lifetime of the browser session (which is why websites can log users out after they close the browser window, even if they didn't hit any Log-off button). If this is the right interpretation than a cookie that has an absolute expiration (and lasts longer than the browser window does) is a "non-session" cookie, but I wouldn't use that language, and it still isn't a "session-less" cookie because it's simply incorrect terminology.

Comment: Mind explaining why you won't call it a "non-session" cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Cookieless session state was developed in ASP.NET at a time when mobile devices such as phones (from over 10 years ago) did not have good support for cookies. With today's modern phones that have modern web browsers, cookies are always supported.

Using cookieless session state and cookieless forms authentication is not recommended because many features of ASP.NET are incompatible with them.

Comment: furthermore, cookieless sessions embed the cookie directly into resource URIs which breaks how the web should work.

Comment: I wanna know about sessionless cookie.

Comment: Not to mention you're passing the session id the URL - not the best practice from a security standpoint, I'd think.